# Function evaluation result

Tags: haskell, equational-reasoning

Im trying to evaluate manually `fc [f1, f2] (\x -> 2) 3` but I don't realize how to match the three parameters: [f1, f2], (\x -> 2) and 3 with the function definition, any help?

The function definition:

```
fc xss = \f -> let ope x y = x . f . y in foldr1 ope xss

f1, f2 :: Int -> Bool
f1 x = (x `mod` 3) == 0
f2 x = (x `mod` 5) == 0
```

Thanks,
Sebastián.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, first do some *η*-expansion

```
fc :: [a->b] -> (b->a) -> a->b
fc xss f = let ope x y = x . f . y in \q -> foldr1 ope xss q
 fc xss f q = let ope x y = x . f . y in foldr1 ope xss q
```

Then perhaps inline the `let`

```
 fc xss f q = foldr1 (\x y -> x . f . y) xss q
```

You can write `[f1, f2]` as `` (==0).(`mod`3) : (==0).(`mod`5) : [] ``.

Now it should be easy enough, remembering that a right-fold simply replaces all `:` with the fold function.

Answer (score 1):

Remember, all functions in Haskell are functions of a single argument to a single result.

Expressions like `func arg1 arg2 arg3` might *look* like a function applied to 3 arguments, but it's really `((func arg1) arg2) arg3)`, where `func arg1` results in a new function, which is applied to `arg2` to get a 3rd function, which is finally applied to `arg3`.

Definitions like `func arg1 arg2 arg3 = ...` are syntactic sugar for equivalent definitions like `func arg1 = \arg2 -> (\arg3 -> ... )`, where we've explicitly written out the intermediate functions produced along the way.

So `fc [f1, f2] (\x -> 2) 3` is applying `fc` to `[f1, f2]`, and then applying the result of that. It's clear how to apply `fc` to one argument (because it's definition has a single argument), so lets just do the first step and see what we get.

```
fc [f1, f2] = \f -> let ope x y = x . f . y in foldr1 ope [f1, f2]
```

That's given us a lambda function, which is something that can be applied. Substituting that into the original expression gives us:

```
(\f -> let ope x y = x . f . y in foldr1 ope [f1, f2]) (\x -> 2) 3
```

Now again we've got a function (`\f -> ...`) applied to one argument (`\x -> 2`). The result of that is applied again (to `3`), but we'll worry about that later.

```
(\f -> let ope x y = x . f . y in foldr1 ope [f1, f2]) (\x -> 2)
  = let ope x y = x . (\x -> 2) . y in foldr1 ope [f1, f2]
```

So that's given us the expression `foldr1 ope [f1, f2]`, with the auxilliary definition `ope` from the `let`; we could substitute that if we want, but I'll let the name `ope` stay as a stand in. Substituting that back in (remembering that we've defined `ope`):

(foldr1 ope [f1, f2]) 3

`foldr` is equivalent to the following:

```
foldr1 f [x] = x
foldr1 f (x:xs) = f x (foldr1 f xs)
```

So we can expand the `foldr1` expression, remembering that `[f1, f2]` is the just another way of writing `f1:[f2]`:

```
foldr1 ope (f1:[f2]) = ope f1 (foldr1 ope [f2])
                     = ope f1 f2
```

Substituting that back in gives us:

```
ope f1 f2 3
```

Now lets make use of the definition for ope we set aside: `ope x y = x . (\x -> 2) . y` (again, we could have substituted this in earlier but it just would've meant copying out the definition everywhere we wrote `ope` above). Remembering that `ope` is really a function of a *single* argument, even though we were allowed to define it looking like it has two arguments for convenience, lets apply it one argument at a time:

```
ope f1 = \y -> f1 . (\x -> 2) . y
```

So we now have:

```
(\y -> f1 . (\x -> 2) . y) f2 3
```

Applying the lambda gives us:

```
(f1 . (\x -> 2) . f2) 3
```

And *finally* we've found that the `3` is an argument to the composition "pipeline" `f1 . (\x -> 2) . f2`. I'll stop here, but you could use the definition of `.` to expand this further and find out what ultimate function `3` is being passed to.

So the 3 values `[f1, f2]`, `(\x -> 2)`, and `3` from your original expression didn't need to be matched directly to the arguments defined for `fc`, because they weren't all arguments to it at all. `[f1, f2]` was the argument to `fc`, `(\x -> 2)` was an argument that was trivially computed by `fc [f1, f2]` (so you could think of it as a "second argument" to `fc` if you want; it would be very easy to rewrite the equation for `fc` so that it appears directly as an argument). `3` on the other hand, was not an argument to a function that's anything close to written directly in the source, it ended up being passed to a function that was *computed* by the expression `fc [f1, f2] (\x -> 2)`.